# "seekg identifier not found"

Tags: include, identifier, seekg

I have a program called main:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
#include"other.h"
int main()
{
//do stuff
}
```

and then other.h:

```
char* load_data(int begin_point,int num_characters)
{
    seekg(begin_point);
    char* return_val=new char[num_characters+1];
    mapdata.getline(return_val,num_characters);
    return return_val;
}
```

and I get the error:

> 'seekg': identifier not found

why do I get this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you defining functions in a header file?? o.O The proper format would be to provide the function prototype in the header file, then create a separate file (perhaps other.cpp) that actually defines the functionality of load_data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seekg is a method from the fstream (declared in istream) class.

You haven't instantiated any.

Take this as an example

```
  ifstream is;
  is.open ("test.txt", ios::binary );

  // get length of file:
  is.seekg (0, ios::end);
```

source: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/seekg/

So, you should

```
char* load_data(int begin_point,int num_characters)
{
    ifstream is;
    is("yourfile.txt") //file is now open for reading. 

    seekg(begin_point);
    char* return_val=new char[num_characters+1];
    mapdata.getline(return_val,num_characters);
    return return_val;
}
```

Take into account what ParoXon commented in your question.

You should create a file other.cpp containing function's load_data implementation.
File other.h should contain function's load_data declaration. In that file (other.h) you should include all files neccesary for functions declared there to work. And dont forget to protect yourself against multiple includes !

File other.h

```
#ifndef __OTHER_H__
#define  __OTHER_H__

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

char* load_data(int,int);//no implementation
#endif
```

File other.cpp

```
#include "other.h" //assumes other.h and other.cpp in same directory

char* load_data(int begin,int amount){
      //load_data implementation
}
```